# Stepping down as a moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I've been inactive for many years at this point, occasionally dropping by and handling some flags but not really participating.

I love this site, but I also don't have the time to give to it, and I really don't need the diamond for anything. So I'm stepping down.

You can read more about this at https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11138/7433

It's been fun, I hope to some day have time to participate again!

Comment: I don't think our paths ever really crossed, but when I look at older posts on main *or* meta I can see how your contributions have shaped the site into what it is today. Thank you for that and all the best with whatever you have moved on to ;)

Comment: Congrats and thank you - as a similarly over-committed person, I think you've contributed significantly to the site over the years. Good luck in your future endeavors!

Answer (score 29):

We spent many happy hours chatting in the very early days of the site, and I was always impressed with your maturity and insight.  I don't think we would have gotten out of beta, let alone graduated and succeeded as much as we have without your help and input.

I was happy with you sticking around as a moderator because we have a great corps and you certainly deserved to have the diamond, but I definitely support your decision to move on.  I wish you the best of luck in all of your endeavors, and I know you'll go even further than you have already!

Answer (score 23):

It has been a pleasure working, discussing, and chatting with you. Your input and guidance, especially in the transition to graduation, are invaluable. I am most thankful to you (and of course jonsca) for showing me how to deal with the plethora of buttons that come along with the diamond. I somewhat still feel like a noob here and I will continue to regard you as my senpai.

You have started quite a few things, help shape the site in its policies, make it a welcoming place, and a useful repository for everyone. I hope you are a little bit happy to see that we are following through with the removal of the homework tag, in the spirit of what you started.

I am honestly sad to see you leave, but I completely understand the decision and support it. I hope there will come a day, when you find some time and pay us a little visit. I wish you all the best for your current and future endeavours.

Answer (score 8):

As a formerly highly active user whose activity sadly has come to a little bit of a standstill in 2018, please allow me to also extend my thanks from the point of view of a non-diamond but nonetheless high-rep user.

While my first post to this site was pre-graduation, my contribution only really started post-graduation so I missed out on a lot of the early shaping work that you performed with the team back then. When I came, I was able to immediately enjoy the fruits of the work. Posting questions and answers on Chemistry.SE has always been enjoyable and the diamond moderator team have a big role in having laid the foundation and for keeping it that way.

I must admit, I only had very few visible interactions with you in your position as a diamond moderator—and frankly, that is a badge of honour for you (but also, obviously, for the remainder of the mod team). As I cannot stop reiterating, this site runs smoothly the vast majority of the time and the mod team is to thank for that. So thank you for all the effort you put in to make it run and for overseeing it while it was running!