# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Chemistry's [third moderator election](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: andselisk] [image: Melanie Shebel]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking ManishEarth who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5639836755034112/0).

Comment: Congrats to you both!!

Comment: To [repeat myself](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11287/2019-community-moderator-election-results?cb=1#comment44737_11287): I really have appreciated all the hard work Manishearth has done on this site.

Comment: Thank you all for your support and invested time! @MelanieShebel Warmest congratulations and all the best with moderating :)

Comment: Congratulations on your fancy new diamonds! Best of luck in your moderation efforts!

Comment: Congratulations, and the best of luck moderating this excellent community!

Answer (score 14):

## Congratulations and welcome to the team!

I am, and I am (almost) certain the other moderators, too, are looking forward to working with you. Thank you for your commitment.

I also want to extend a big thank you to all other candidates, I am very glad that (at least for me) the choice was a tough one, and I think each of you would have been a good choice. I'm looking forward to your continuous support and contributions.

I thank all members of our community who participated in any form to this election process.

Lastly, I would like to extend another big thank you to Manish, to whom we officially say good-bye today. He has had a big impact on our community, and his legacy will be well remembered, and many things wouldn't have been possible without his contributions.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: You **don't** *speak* **for** ME!!!!!

Answer (score 14):

**Congrats to you both!!**

Thanks to everyone who ran. You were all amazing candidates and are highly valued users, and I hope that all of you continue to contribute to the site.

To Manish: best of luck in all of your future endeavors.  I'll re-emphasize what I [answered](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4395/) on the question announcing your retirement,

> We spent many happy hours chatting in the very early days of the site, and I was always impressed with your maturity and insight. I don't think we would have gotten out of beta, let alone graduated and succeeded as much as we have without your help and input.

Answer (score 11):

## Congrats, @andselisk and @MelanieShebel!

I take upon myself this great privilege to be the first non-mod user to congratulate you both officially.

## For Andselisk

I knew you had great potential to be a moderator ever since I joined the site. You have worked hard till now, so I know you will keep up the good work!

## For Melanie

I haven't spoken directly to you(yet), but I know you're a great addition to the mod team. I feel like I know a bit about you from your chemistry jokes page I read quite some time ago. `(I didn't know protons were catholic either)`

## For other candidates

You all were very deserving candidates and the community (me included) has a lot of respect for you guys!

.

## For ManishEarth

Although I haven't seen you in live action on this site, I can see the impact you've created. The legacy you've left behind. The fruits of your hard work and dedication that new users (like myself) enjoy today. Thank you for your contributions!

---

I hope we can all work together and make Chemistry.SE a great place!