# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Chemistry Stack Exchange's [fourth moderator election](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: Buck Thorn] [image: Todd Minehardt]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes! Let's also thank [jonsca](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/73/jonsca), who recently stepped down, for their work as a moderator over the years.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6194717000728576).

Comment: Congratulations to @BuckThorn and @ToddMinehardt! Best of luck, I know you will both do a fantastic job!

Comment: Commiserations to the runner-up Tyberius!

Comment: Thanks @Tyberius and to all who participated!

Comment: Thanks @Tyberius and the other candidates and all who voted and commented.

Comment: Congrats @ToddMinehardt @ BuckThorn, you guys will be great mods.. and I'll be around to support you guys :D

Comment: congratulations to you both and good luck!

Answer (score 16):

#### [Todd Minehardt](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/865)

Congratulations and welcome to the ♢-team! I am delighted to see Todd finally elected as a  mod. User 856 should've been the winner during [2019 election](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4503) as a more experienced member with a long history of positive contributions, not me who was a newbie at that time (and still is in some areas). Thank you for being loyal and unbiased to this community for such a long period of time.

#### [Buck Thorn](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/69830)

Congratulations and welcome to the ♢-team! As a newer member, you managed to be acknowledged as a professional physical chemist in a short period of time. You proved yourself to be a fair user who participates on a regular basis and who is not afraid of taking responsibility and improving yourself. I am truly happy to see you among the mods and I hope you'll find your new moderation tools useful and fun.

#### [Tyberius](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/41556)

Let me first take my hat off. Not that I'm still wearing one from the Winter Bash, it's that I know you (well, your *internet persona* at least:) ) since the moment I joined Chemistry.SE and to me you always made an impression of a dedicated perfectionist who is  well-versed in theory. Your actions and decisions were always weighted and full of sobriety. You would make a hell of a mod on CSE and I envy your [colleagues from MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). Shall there be another election, I really hope to see your name on the list of candidates one more time.

#### [Shoubhik R Maiti](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/33586)

I enjoy reading your Q&As of theoretical and organic chemistry here and on MMSE. You are curious, it looks like you love to learn and have no problems with receiving critics. Don't let the fact you didn't become the mod this time to get you down. I'm sure you can easily apply and win once the next election takes place. In the meantime, post, flag, vote and have fun.

#### [Safdar Faisal](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/95133)

It's amazing to see how quickly you adapted to the quirks of the CSE and started to participate full speed. You make an impression of a quick learner and the amount of work and rep points you've invested before the election is really impressive. Again, don't feel sad it didn't work out this time. You brought a lot of goodies and whipped up the community quite a bit. Keep up the good work and best of luck next election!

#### Thank you all for playing and voting.

Comment: Now there are more mods, I expect a marshal  badge soon :P

Comment: I'm not going to write another answer, I'm just hitchhiking on that one. Congratulations to our new team members and a big thank you to all participants. I hope to see you around actively.