# Where is our moderator Melanie Shebel?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I know this could be a rather annoying thing to ask because I'm not allowed to control/keep in check whatever the moderators have to do.
And I know it feels wrong to put it this way. But I mean no offence :/

I just wanted to ask why isn't one of our moderators - [Melanie Shebel](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/402/melanie-shebel) seen as much as other moderators?
It is a very subjective thing. Please don't feel awkward that I said it like that.
I just mean to say that, '**I**' didn't see the moderator active recently.
I've had the chance to even actively interact with a few moderators.
I checked Melanie's profile and didn't find recent stuff so I just was curious to know?
Is it like moderators don't have to actively participate in stuff?
Doesn't that seem unfair to other moderators?

Again, I'm looking at it superficially and reporting what I noticed. I have no clue if all moderators are contributing their fair part on the inside. I am not indicating anything like 'our moderators aren't actively doing things' etc. Maybe I'm just inquisitive.

Comment: What's the point of asking such questions? Mods have no concrete obligation to be active. Seems recently they take away diamonds for half a year inactivity. One could say sarcasticly: mod inactivity problem solved!

Comment: @Mithoron _I believe_ that it brings the community together and bonds them. Having a need for awareness about a community that you're a part of seemed natural to me. And such a question was asked about Loong as well, so I didn't hesitate asking about Melanie. As I mentioned, you could say I'm inquisitive.

Comment: It's ok. [I have inquired about Loong](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4879/did-something-happened-to-loongs-account). It's good that you are concerned about others. The moderators work really hard. We can see the effort being put through so that the community runs smooth. But, sometimes situation go out of hand and you have to back up a little bit. I am not going into the details but I am sure she will come back once the situation is clear. Let's be optimistic and hope for the best :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See Melanie's answer here on [Mother Meta (meta.stackexchange.com)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper/344403#344403).

> I am a moderator on Chemistry and am suspending moderating activity.

Due to multiple reasons, as mentioned in the main post, Loong, or Faded Giant as he was known, decided to terminate his stack exchange account.

Jonsca also stepped down recently from the moderator position. See the [election post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4972/2021-community-moderator-election-results).

> Let's also thank jonsca, who recently stepped down, for their work as a moderator over the years.

All of this led to the work being put on our, previously, 3 moderators. [Andselisk ♦](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/41328/andselisk), [Martin - マーチン ♦](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/4945/martin-%e3%83%9e%e3%83%bc%e3%83%81%e3%83%b3), [Orthocresol ♦](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/16683/orthocresol). Upon the request of these three moderators, the SE team decided to conduct the moderator elections that concluded recently and brought in two great members of our community into the front-lines. [Buck Thorn ♦](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/69830/buck-thorn) and [Todd Minehardt ♦](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/865/todd-minehardt).

Also, just as a side note, all our moderators are real people with their own careers and yet they take the time to curate and moderate this community that has helped us all a lot. But they aren't the only people who can do this and I encourage everyone who has the time to do their part by flagging, voting and closing. A big thanks to the community that has come so far and has helped us all a lot.

[image]

Comment: Man, I miss the nomenclature god :-(